# camera calibration using vanishing points

Tags: three.js, 3d, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am trying to "calibrate" a virtual camera to align with the one in a photo.

Basically an implementation of what is this report
http://www.irisa.fr/prive/kadi/Reconstruction/paper.ps.gz

So basically what it is about is that I manually match the points of a book in an image, and draw out the vanishing points from the edges created, and based on the math in the article I get the focal point, and I *think* that is working

```
export function computeFocalLength(vanishingPoints: [Vec2, Vec2], principalPoint: Vec2): number {
    const fV = vanishingPoints[0]
    const fU = vanishingPoints[1]
    const fUfV = fU.sub(fV).normalize();
    const fVP = principalPoint.sub(fV);
    const distance = fUfV.dot(fVP); 
    let pUV = fUfV.scale(distance).add(fV);

    const ppUV = principalPoint.sub(pUV); 
    const fVpUV = fV.sub(pUV);
    const fUpUV = fU.sub(pUV);

    let fsq = fVpUV.length * fUpUV.length - Math.pow(ppUV.length, 2);

    const f = Math.sqrt(fsq); 
    return f
}
```

at the very least the dot product of `fV` and `fU` is equal to `0` when I move it into 3D by setting `z = computeFocalLength(...)` on both vectors.

But the issue is that I can't seem to get the rotation to align.

the code seems pretty straight forwards, and I think it aligns well with the article

```
export function computeRotationMatrix(focalLength: number, vanishingPoints: [Vec2, Vec2], principalPoint: Vec2): Mat3 {
    const fV = vanishingPoints[0]
    const fU = vanishingPoints[1]
    const u = principalPoint.sub(fU).toVec3(-focalLength).normalize()
    const v = principalPoint.sub(fV).toVec3(-focalLength).normalize()
    const w = u.cross(v);

    return new Mat3([
        u.x, v.x, w.x,
        u.y, v.y, w.y,
        u.z, v.z, w.z
    ])
}
```

although when applying this to a three.js perspective camera, nothing seems to align with the points I have placed in the corners of my book.

```
let m = computeRotationMatrix(...).invert();
let tM = new THREE.Matrix4(
                    m[0], m[1], m[2], 0,
                    m[3], m[4], m[5], 0,
                    m[6], m[7], m[8], 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 1
                )
                camera.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(tM);
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

Am I doing something that is just obviously wrong?

I guess to make it somewhat easier here are 2 images from the article that might explain it better than me
[image: Figure]

[image: Math]